# So, because flutter_post depends on both google_sign_in ^5.2.4 and quiver ^2.0.1, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, google-signin

I'm not sure what to do... here's my output:

[flutter_post] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_post...
Because google_sign_in >=5.4.0 depends on google_sign_in_platform_interface ^2.2.0 and google_sign_in >=5.2.0 <5.4.0 depends on google_sign_in_platform_interface ^2.1.0, google_sign_in >=5.2.0 requires google_sign_in_platform_interface ^2.1.0.
And because google_sign_in_platform_interface >=2.0.0 depends on quiver ^3.0.0, google_sign_in >=5.2.0 requires quiver ^3.0.0.
So, because flutter_post depends on both google_sign_in ^5.2.4 and quiver ^2.0.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_post depends on both google_sign_in ^5.2.4 and quiver ^2.0.1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.13.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.17
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.4
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.14
  email_validator: ^2.0.1
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.17
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.6
  swipedetector: ^1.2.0
  flutter_swiper_null_safety: ^1.0.2

  quiver: ^2.0.1

  # google_sign_in_platform_interface: ^2.2.0
  # google_sign_in: ^5.4.0
  # quiver: ^3.0.0
  # google_sign_in: ^5.4.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update **quiver: ^2.0.1**. to **quiver: ^3.1.0**